# How to send primitive data from C program running on Ubuntu over network to Android device application?

Tags: javascript, android, c, linux, ubuntu

Problem: I am running a simple C program on Ubuntu (to represent a server) that outputs some primitive data. How would I send send this data over a local network router to be used by a simple application on an Android device?

Background: I have been (and still am) reading about socket programming, threading, and the json C library. Based on my searches, I am guessing that the answer to my question is not simple. Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Note: I should mention that I cannot send this data to an external server due to latency issues. The server code is written in C and that can't be changed.

Expected result example: An integer result is forwarded from a C program running on Ubuntu to an Android application for use in a calculation.

Comment: Suggestion: start with plain simple text (send `1023` possibly followed by newline) and if that doesn't work look into alternatives (JSON, XML, ...)

Comment: Look for a simple socket example. You can probably find a simple chat example that you can modify or learn from.